# How do I get the HTML output of a UserControl in .NET (C#)?

Tags: c#, html, .net, user-controls

If I create a UserControl and add some objects to it, how can I grab the HTML it would render?

ex.

```
UserControl myControl = new UserControl();
myControl.Controls.Add(new TextBox());

// ...something happens

return strHTMLofControl;
```

I'd like to just convert a newly built UserControl to a string of HTML.

Comment: Please, make azamsharp's answer "accepted", if his solution works for you. Be a good SO member :)

Comment: You will also need to be sure System.Web is added to your references so you can import System.Web.UI (which HtmlTextWriter needs)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can render the control using `Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter)`.

Feed `StringWriter` to the `HtmlTextWriter`.

Feed `StringBuilder` to the `StringWriter`.

Your generated string will be inside the `StringBuilder` object.

Here's a code example for this solution:

```
string html = String.Empty;
using (TextWriter myTextWriter = new StringWriter(new StringBuilder()))
{
    using (HtmlTextWriter myWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(myTextWriter))
    {
        myControl.RenderControl(myWriter);
        html = myTextWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: you could also add the control in a "live" controls collection to avoid random exceptions.

Comment: This answer could be vastly improved by simply having the code sample here with the actual code.

Comment: @theJerm: here? where? Can't see any link

Comment: StringWriter and HtmlTextWriter instances are not being disposed properly. Wrap them in `using` block.

Answer (score 32):

```
//render control to string
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
HtmlTextWriter h = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(b));
this.LoadControl("~/path_to_control.ascx").RenderControl(h);
string controlAsString = b.ToString();
```

Comment: How to put properties of usercontrol here. Please post it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491018/error-executing-child-request-for-handler-system-web-ui-page-while-convertin

Answer (score 14):

```
UserControl uc = new UserControl();
MyCustomUserControl mu = (MyCustomUserControl)uc.LoadControl("~/Controls/MyCustomUserControl.ascx");

TextWriter tw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

mu.RenderControl(hw);

return tw.ToString();
```

Comment: `LoadControl` solved my problem. (creating a new instance doesn't work)

Answer (score 7):

Seven years late, but this deserves to be shared.

The generally accepted solution - `StringBuilder` into `StringWriter` into `HtmlWriter` into `RenderControl` - is good. But there are some gotchas, which I unfortunately ran across while trying to do the same thing. Some controls will throw errors if they're not inside of a `Page`, and some will throw errors if they're not inside of a `<form>` with `runat="server"`. The ScriptManager control exhibits both of these behaviours.

[I eventually found a workaround here.](http://harouny.com/2012/10/15/render-asp-net-controls-user-controls-to-html-by-code/) The gist of it is basically just instantiating a new Page and Form before doing the writer work:

```cs
Page page = new Page();
page.EnableEventValidation = false;

HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm();
form.Name = "form1";
page.Controls.Add(form1);

MyControl mc = new MyControl();
form.Controls.Add(mc);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

page.RenderControl(writer);

return sb.ToString();
```

Unfortunately, this gives you more markup than you actually need (since it includes the dummy form). And the ScriptManager will still fail for some arcane reason I haven't puzzled out yet. Honestly, it's a whole lot of trouble and not worth doing; the whole point of generating controls in the code-behind is so that you don't have to fiddle around with the markup, after all.

Comment: Exactly - thank you Reikim.

The other part of these approaches that is bothering me is the quantity of instantiation that it can require. The amount of overhead is nagging at me - all to sling a string back to a browser.

Answer (score 4):

override the RenderControl method

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
{       
   output.Write("<br>Message from Control : " + Message);       
   output.Write("Showing Custom controls created in reverse" +
                                                    "order");         
   // Render Controls.
   RenderChildren(output);
}
```

This will give you access to the writer which the HTML will be written to.

You may also want to look into the adaptive control architecture of asp.net
[adaptive control architecture of asp.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67276kc5.aspx) where you can 'shape' the default html output from controls.

Answer (score 1):

Call its `.RenderControl()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize the `HttpServerUtility.Execute` Method, available through `HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute`:

```
var page = new Page();
var myControl = (MyControl)page.LoadControl("mycontrol.ascx");
myControl.SetSomeProperty = true;
page.Controls.Add(myControl);
var sw = new StringWriter();
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, sw, preserveForm: false);
```

The benefit would be that you also trigger the Page_Load event of your user control.

MSDN documentation can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb04e8f7(v=vs.110).aspx.