# insert html listbox items from database

Tags: c#, html, database, listbox

how do i insert items into an html listbox from a database?
im using asp c#. i cant make the listbox run at server because the application wont work if i do that. so i have to insert values from a database into an html listbox. I just need to display 1 column of data. cheers..

Comment: What about adding runat="server" to your ListBox is giving you problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Literal, build the HTML for the listbox, and set the .Text of the Literal.

You could either string together the HTML for the listbox [manually](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/forms/select.html), or you could build a Listbox in C# and use [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288409/how-do-i-get-the-html-output-of-a-usercontrol-in-net-c) to have C# export the HTML string to the Literal.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this I can think of:

First, you can place an `<asp:Placeholder />` tag on the page and generate the listbox in code:

```
var select = new HtmlSelect() { Size = 5 };

//assuming the data has been placed in an IEnumarble
foreach (var item in items)
{
    select.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Value = item });
}
selectPlaceholder.Controls.Add(select);
```

Second, you could create a WebService or ashx handler to provide the data and populate the list from javascript.