# Can a user control be rendered on the click event of a button?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have created a user control which actually creates an empty dialog box for application form. I wanted to render this user control on the click event of a button(like we render partial views). I have an .aspx page that contains a button. On clicking the button the user control that creates a dialog, opens up. Below is the jquery code written to open the dialog in a user control:

**Jquery**

```
createAliasPopUpForm: function (rowNumberId) {
    // debugger;
    var self = this;
    var dat = $("input[id*='hdnAliasRecordmetaData']").val();
    self.metaDataColumns = JSON.parse(dat);
    //debugger;   
    // now bind update data to pop up
    if (self.metaDataColumns.length > 0) {

        if (rowNumberId != 'undefined' && rowNumberId != null) {
            self.rowNumber = rowNumberId;
            // fill alias record to meta data
            var listdata = $("input[id*='hdnAliasRecordList']").val();
            var aliasList = JSON.parse(listdata);
            if (aliasList.Rows.length > 0) {
                $.each(aliasList.Rows, function (i, val) {
                    if (this.RowNumber == rowNumberId) {
                        self.fillAliasRecord(self.metaDataColumns, this.Columns);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }

        }
        else {
            // right now cloumn list has MDM record value so need to clear that value only
            $.each(self.metaDataColumns, function (i, val) {
                this.Value = '';
            });
        }



        // sort array
        //self.metaDataColumns.sort(common.dynamicSortMultiple("GroupOrder", "MetadataId"));
        self.metaDataColumns.sort(common.dynamicSortMultiple("GroupOrder", "ColumnNumber"));
        self.createPopupHtml(self.metaDataColumns, rowNumberId);
        self.init();

        $('#popUpHeader').find('h4').remove();
        $('#popUpHeader').append('  <h4 class="modal-title" >Alias Record</h4>');
        $("#updateConfirmPopUp").dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            width: 600,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            modal: true,
            show: { effect: 'blind' }
        });
    }



},
```

**userControl**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AddAlias.ascx.cs" Inherits="OCM.Phoenix.WebToolsFramework.Server.Modules.MDMAdmin.AddAlias" %>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js") %>'></script>
<script language="javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="../Scripts/Common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="../Scripts/AdminEdit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnAliasRecordmetaData" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnAliasRecordList" runat="server" />
<script>
$(function () {
    adminEditForm.createAliasPopUpForm();
});
</script>
```

code behind file just contains the load event

**aspx page**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AddAliasPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="Modules_MDMDataHub_AddAliasPage" %>

<%@ Register Src="UserControls/AddAlias.ascx" TagPrefix="uc" TagName="alias" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/AdminEdit.js"></script>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <uc:alias ID="alias" runat="server" />
            <br />

            <asp:button ID="btn1" OnClick="btn1_Click" runat="server">    </asp:button>

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Although, I have created the click event of the button, that calls the below function to render the html of the user control. but its actuaaly not working as it keeps giving me an errer as the hdnmetadatavalue must be inside the form tag. I did it but still i get the error. Am i doing something wrong here? Please help

```
private string RenderControl()
{
    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    using (var stWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb))
    using (var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stWriter))
    {
        var p = new Page();

        var ctrl = (AddAlias)p.LoadControl("~/Modules/MDMDataHub/UserControls/AddAlias.ascx");
        ctrl.Visible = true;

        // do your own init logic if needed

        p.Controls.Add(ctrl);
        ctrl.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By reviewing your code:

```
var ctrl = (AddAlias)p.LoadControl("~/Modules/MDMDataHub/UserControls/AddAlias.ascx");
// ... other lines
ctrl.RenderControl(htmlWriter);
```

I assume you are trying to call `RenderControl` method for user control to HTML  rendering, where the page will raise form tag exception if the user control was rendered outside defined form tag with `runat="server"`.

Use `Page.VerifyRenderingInServerForm` method on page code behind to ensure all user controls render properly:

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control) {
    // nothing to override here
}

public override boolean EnableEventValidation {
    get { return false; }
}
```

Reference: [UserControl's RenderControl is asking for a form tag in (C# .NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334382/usercontrols-rendercontrol-is-asking-for-a-form-tag-in-c-net/338061#338061)