# Get user control html in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, user-controls

i'm trying to load a user control from codebehind service and get it's html value. However there's a repeater in that control that isn't getting loaded/initialized so it's always null

i get

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

within the **loadOrderInvoiceView** function when it tries to

```
// fill repeater
this.rptView.DataSource = result;
this.rptView.DataBind();
```

at the line where it says **this.rptView.DataSource = result;**... i've tried to debug and for some reason **this.rptView** is null

And here's the service call

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

    //ctrl.RenderControl(hw);

    myControls.OrderInvoiceView oiv = new myControls.OrderInvoiceView();
    oiv.loadOrderInvoiceView(OID);// load the control with order id
    oiv.RenderControl(hw);

    return sb.ToString();
```

thanks in advance for any ideas. I'm using .net 4

Comment: How are you initializing `this.rptView`?

Comment: i tought making the control will automatically initialize it.. anyway i'll be answering my own question. i just found out how to get around it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the HTML output of a UserControl in .NET (C#)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288409/how-do-i-get-the-html-output-of-a-usercontrol-in-net-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found out how to get around it

```
    Page p = new Page();
    myControls.OrderInvoiceView oiv = (myControls.OrderInvoiceView)p.LoadControl("~/myControls/OrderInvoiceView.ascx");
```

instead of

```
myControls.OrderInvoiceView oiv = new myControls.OrderInvoiceView();
```

final result

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb);
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);

        Page p = new Page();
        myControls.OrderInvoiceView oiv = (myControls.OrderInvoiceView)p.LoadControl("~/myControls/OrderInvoiceView.ascx");

        //myControls.OrderInvoiceView oiv = new myControls.OrderInvoiceView();
        oiv.loadOrderInvoiceView(OID);
        oiv.RenderControl(hw);

        return sb.ToString();
```