# How can I call bind method of grid through webmethod

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, data-binding

This is my method to bind in code behind,I want to call it through web method

```
Private Sub BindData()
    Dim objtable As New DataTable("projectinfoclass")
    Dim Conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conString").ConnectionString)
    Dim Cmd As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from ProjectInfoNew", Conn)

    Cmd.Fill(objtable)
    projectinfolist.Clear()

    For Each dr As DataRow In objtable.Rows
        projectinfolist.Add(New Projectinfoclass With {
            .ProjectNumber = dr("ProjectNumber").ToString(),
            .projectId = dr("Projectid").ToString(),
            .Projectname = dr("ProjectName").ToString(),
            .projectmodifiedDate = dr("ProjectmodifiedDate").ToString(),
            .Recordupdateddate = dr("Recordupdateddate").ToString(),
            .ProjectLocation = dr("ProjectLocation").ToString(),
            .LocationServerName = dr("LocationServerName").ToString(), .ProjectModifiedBy = dr("ProjectModifiedBy").ToString(),
            .DBServer = dr("DBServer").ToString(),
            .DBName = dr("DBName").ToString(),
            .Flag = Nothing})
    Next

    GridView1.DataSource = objtable
    GridView1.DataBind()
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

put your GridView in a usercontrol and follow the solutions here:

[How do I get the HTML output of a UserControl in .NET (C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288409/how-do-i-get-the-html-output-of-a-usercontrol-in-net-c)

Answer (score 0):

1) Keep the data source and bind bits in the page code behind, move the rest into a web method. The web method can be called in the code behind and you use the result.
or
2) move code into web method as above but use as an object data source in the aspx and that removes all the code behind wiring up.

I hope that's what you're after.

Comment: How can i use stored procedure in the above code instead of sql query

Comment: There are lots of questions, answers and material on that, a simple search will give you all you need.